# Not able to mutate data on the front end with Apollo

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to build a reservations app on React-Native using Apollo client with GraphQl

I'm not able to call a mutation on the front end.

Below is some code with schema and what my mutation looks like.

What am I doing wrong?

Schema:

```
createReservation(
  data: ReservationCreateInput!
): Reservation!
type Reservation
implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  hotelName: String!
  arrivalDate: String!
  departureDate: String!
}
```

My mutation:

```
const addReservationMutation = gql`
  mutation createReservation(
    $data: {
      name: String!
      hotelName: String!
      arrivalDate: String!
      departureDate: String!
    })

   {
     name
  }
`;
```

Button wrapped in Mutation component

```
<Mutation mutation={addReservationMutation}>
      {(addReservation, { data }) => (
        <Button
          title="Reserve your!"
          onPress={() => {
            addReservation({
              variables: {
                name: "Joe",
                hotelName: "LemonTree",
                arrivalDate: "06/05/2019",
                departureDate: "06/12/2019"
              }
            });
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Mutation>
```

Error:

```
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {
74 Requiring module "index.js", which threw an exception: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {

GraphQL request (3:12)
2:   mutation createReservation(
3:     $data: {
              ^
4:       name: String!


NativeModules @ RNDebuggerWorker.js:1
c @ RNDebuggerWorker.js:1
"index.js", which threw an exception: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {

GraphQL request (3:12)
2:   mutation createReservation(
3:     $data: {
              ^
4:       name: String!

handleException @ 
c @ RNDebuggerWorker.js:1
…:74 Requiring module "index.js", which threw an exception: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {

GraphQL request (3:12)
2:   mutation createReservation(
3:     $data: {
              ^
4:       name: String!
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what's wrong. Are you seeing errors in the console? If you check the network tab under dev tools, what's the response from the server? If the request fails, the response from the server will typically include an `errors` array with additional details as to what went wrong. Please update your question and provide more information.

Comment: Updated with errors

Answer (score 1):

Use input types when you need composited fields on the mutations, please check

https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/

Your schema, mutation and code should look something similar to this with the input types.

Schema:

```
input ReservationInput {
  name: String!
  hotelName: String!
  arrivalDate: String!
  departureDate: String!
}
```

Mutation:

```
mutation createReservation($data: ReservationInput ){
     name
}
```

Component:

```
<Mutation mutation={addReservationMutation}>
      {(addReservation, { data }) => (
        <Button
          title="Reserve your!"
          onPress={() => {
            addReservation({
              variables: {
                data: {
                  name: "Joe",
                  hotelName: "LemonTree",
                  arrivalDate: "06/05/2019",
                  departureDate: "06/12/2019"
               }
              }
            });
          }}
        />
      )}
</Mutation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mutation looks wrong to me. Shouldn't it be more like this:

```
const addReservationMutation = gql`
  mutation onCreateReservation(
    $data: {
      name: String!
      hotelName: String!
      arrivalDate: String!
      departureDate: String!
    }) {
     createReservation(data: $data) {
       name
    }
  }
`;
```